# How can I create a video conference in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a multi-party video app, where the user does not need to sign up, kinda like Omegle but instead of 1-on-1 video chat, it'll be multi-party.
I am being puzzled by this task as it seems most libraries are very unclear and implement 1-on-1 video calls instead of multiparty random rooms.
Any guidance regarding that situation?

Comment: not an appropriate question; you need a minimum reproducible example or at least show what you've tried so far

Comment: Questions need to be narrow and specific to be on-topic here -- and there are a lot of architectural and tooling decisions you need to make up-front on your own (tool selection choices are explicitly off-topic).

Comment: Note that the kind of tool you're talking about building generally _can't_ be done (in a way that's going to be practically useful for more than a very small number of clients) without a central server doing the multiplexing -- otherwise the amount of network bandwidth client each needs explodes as each client sends its outbound video _directly to every other client_ instead of just to a single server and letting the server mirror it out (potentially after cutting down to a lower resolution on a client-by-client basis).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the useful information!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy When it comes to tooling, I tried around 5 different tools, none works. Is it possible to create it from scratch?

Comment: It's possible to create _anything_ from scratch; it's a question of time and resources. Most of the folks I've seen doing this recently, though, tend to build on top of Jitsi; building something completely new is an expensive, slow process.

Comment: Really, you'd do well to spend some time studying the design of Jitsi even if you aren't going to use it, to know what the moving parts are, why they're needed, what factors went into design decisions (even if you might end up eventually making different ones), etc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I will definitely take a look at Jitsi, thanks!